# Jquery array returns after post

Tags: jquery, arrays, post

Hi I am doing one checkscript with jquery and php
I have written this :

```
$.post("chatController.php", {
    ssha:"<?php echo $sechs1;?>", 
    user: "<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>", 
    class:1
 }, function(data){ 
    $.each(data, alert(this));
 }, "json");
```

And from the PHP file I get something like :

```
echo json_encode(array("John","2pm"));
```

This array can have 0,1,2....unlimitied entries..
How I alert each of this entrie one by one ?

Perhaps something like:

```
For each data > alert(this)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `alert` immediately and passing its return value to `$.each`. You have to pass a *function reference* instead:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item){
    alert(item);
});
```

---

Be careful with using `class` as property name. It is a reserved keyword and you could have problems with it in browsers. Either put it in a string:

```
'class': 1
```

or rename it.

Answer (score 1):

to have proper json you must have key value pairs in your php array, something like:

```
json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm"));
```

to list all object properties you can do:

```
for(var prop in data){
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){  // this prevents inherited properties
    console.log(prop);
  }
}
```

Comment: normal array is still a proper json.. just I dont write names like "name" and "time".. They are coming as int > 0,1,2,3,4
if I alert(data['0']) its coming correct entry > John

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are searching for [`JQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: But the documentation shows how to use that function. He has to pass a function as second parameter, as someone else already said.